# Elasticsearch set `ignore_above` for all fields in multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

I have an elastic-search with `200+` indices. Documents sometimes contain long text fields which are useless and take too much indexing power.

I want need to set limit with [`ignore_above`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/ignore-above.html) for all fields in all indices automatically.
I'm trying to use [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) for that.

I've found examples how to set it up for specific fields by name.
**How can I apply it for all (current and future) indices and fields?**

Answer (score 1):

> How can I apply it for all (current and future) indices and fields?

The settings in the template will only be applicable to the new indices. For existing indices, you need to update the `mappings` for individual indices.

The way to apply this setting across all indices varies between different Elasticsearch versions. I can show you for two of the versions I have tried and know it works.

ES 2.4

```
    "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "string_fields": {
                    "mapping": {
                        "ignore_above": 10922,
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "match": "*"
                }
            }
        ]
        },
        "<your object type>": {
    <other settings>
    }
}
```

ES 6.1

```
"mappings": {
    "_default_" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [
            {
                "string_fields" : {
                    "mapping" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 8191,
                        "index": true
                },
                "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                "match" : "*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "<your object type>": {
    <other settings>
    }
}
```

`mappings` under `_default_` will be applicable to all the object types and can be overridden using setting under `<your object type>`.

HTH